# Error: Android Packager (Access is denied) building APK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

(Note, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 on Windows 8.1)

My app was building fine for debugging locally, and then I tried to create the singed APK using the following steps:

1. Clicked Build->Generate Signed APK...
2. In the Wizard dialog, I clicked "Create new"
3. For the Key store path, I added a new jks file "passwordispassword"

   - Password: password.
   - Confirm: password
   - Alias: key
   - etc...
4. Back in the Wizard, click next and then click Finish.

The build started, but I got the error:

> Error:Android Packager: [DRMTest1] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\mobile\testing\DRMTest1\out\production\DRMTest1\DRMTest1.apk (Access is denied)

And now, even if I try to use Build->Make project the same error happens. Any idea what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: i use android studio 0.80 have same problem

Comment: i have same problem using android studio